# Windows 7 Save As dialogue missing folders

Tags: windows-7, save-as

I have a user who is having trouble with all Save As dialogue boxes.

Here are examples from [Word 2010](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nX59H.png)
[image]

and [Notepad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Penzd.png)
[image]

Notice that the folders are completely missing.

Here are things I've tried:

- Logging in as a different user - the dialogue boxes work correctly.
- I initially thought it was just an Office issue, so I did a repair, but that didn't help.
- Clicking "Hide Folders" and "Browse Folders" to see if it would reset the view, but that didn't help either.
- Searching for others with this issue.  I have yet to find a post about this exact issue.

Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up recreating the user's profile, which solved the problem.  I wasn't able to find a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and was reluctant to redo the profile and lose settings. After a while I figured something: The "line" below 'Organize' and 'New Folder' try dragging it down!  It's a resizeable window that probably got minimized by accident - that's what happened to me I think.

So, maybe it's all still there just hidden, below "New folder" & above the filename dialogue 'box':

[image: hidden folders]